# How to properly access AtttachedTemplate when using Word.Interop?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I am trying to create Microsoft Word documents from my C# application using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library. I use a template file to hold several building blocks and scaffold a document with them like this:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Word.Application wdApplication = null;
dynamic wdDocument = null;

try {
  wdApplication = new Word.Application();
  wdDocument = wdApplication.Documents.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.Template);
  wdDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("Agenda.Header").Insert(wdDocument.Paragraphs.Last().Range);
  // ...
} catch { }
```

This way everything works fine. The problem is because I'm declaring `wdDocument` as `dynamic` I don't get any IntelliSense hints, which would otherwise save me a lot of time and effort.

However when I try declaring `wdDocument` as `Word.Document` I get the following error:

> Error CS1545  Property, indexer, or event '_Document.AttachedTemplate' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods '_Document.get_AttachedTemplate()' or '_Document.set_AttachedTemplate(ref object)'

I also tried declaring `wdDocument` as `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document`, but that only introduced type conversion errors between `wdApplication` an `wdDocument`.

What is the correct way of declaring a document type or accessing building blocks that are stored in the attached template?

Comment: @mjwills I've seen that link, but unfortunately it does not help. It is about setting the attached template, not accessing its properties. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So `get_AttachedTemplate` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you share the compiler error you get when you try and use `get_AttachedTemplate()`?

Comment: @mjwills Sure. When I'm trying to use `get_AttachedTemplate` [like this](https://gist.github.com/heuels/6fd6d192dae7a61ac41f41ec81cd6631) I get the following error on line 13: `CS1955 Error Non-invocable member 'Template.BuildingBlockEntries' cannot be used like a method.`.

Comment: Do you think `BuildingBlockEntries` is a method? Or more like an array / list? How do you reference array entries in C#?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. I found an article on MSDN that specifically explains how to deal with building blocks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457184(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I still wonder though why my original method worked, when I was declaring `wdDocument` as `dynamic`.

Comment: `dynamic` uses different rules for determining whether a method is a property getter. _It will accept a method as being a property getter when it **technically** isn't._

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to @mjwills who got me on the right track. This is my final code for creating a Word document with building blocks:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public class Agenda {
  public static void Create() {
    Word.Application wordApplication = null;
    Word.Document wdDocument = null;
    Word.Template wdTemplate = null;
    Word.BuildingBlock wdBuildingBlock = null;

    object paramBBCategory = "Agenda";
    object paramBBName = "Header";

    try {
      wordApplication = new Word.Application();
      wdDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.Template);
      wdTemplate = (Word.Template)wdDocument.get_AttachedTemplate();

      wdBuildingBlock = wdTemplate
        .BuildingBlockTypes.Item(Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeQuickParts)
        .Categories.Item(ref paramBBCategory)
        .BuildingBlocks.Item(ref paramBBName);
      wordBuildingBlock.Insert(wdDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range);
    } catch { }
  }
}
```

See this great article on MSDN for reference: [Retrieving Custom Building Blocks from Templates in Word 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457184(v=office.12).aspx)